# accurate conversion (currency and it cents with fmod)

Tags: c++11

If I convert 5 USD to Euro, it should be 4.45 or 4 euro and 45 cent
the problem is that I get 4 and 0.55 instead of 0.45 or is there a way to get 45 cent??

```
enter code here
int main() {

double usd = 0, euro = 0;
double fixeuro = 0.89;
cout << "Please add amount to convert it\n";
cin >> usd;
int conv = usd * fixeuro;
cout << conv  << "\n";
cout << fmod(usd,fixeuro);

return 0;}
```

Comment: Did you already check if the `usd` value has been read correctly? (`cout << usd`)

Comment: sorry I meant 4 instead of 5 (already corrected it)

Comment: I am really sorry I have just corrected every thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the correct amount is `double conv = usd * fixeuro;` Then if you want to get just the euros, that's `int euros = conv;` and just the eurocents is `int eurocents = 100 * (conv - euros);` Or, if you want, you can use `100 * fmod(conv, 1.0)`.

`fmod(usd,fixeuro)` doesn't appear to have any obvious meaning. It's what you are left with when you have 5 USD and start throwing away exactly 89 cents at a time until you have less than 89 cents. 89 US cents do not correspond to any interesting amount in euros, and US cents are not eurocents, so it isn't quite clear what you get from this.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution , my goal using fmod is same as modulo, I thought I would get whats left after comma